# How in c# make file.txt when click on button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is code for windows forms aplication:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

How to create a file, `file.txt`, when you click on the button?

Answer (score 2):

You have many methods you can use on `File`, like `File.Create`. This simply creates or overwrites a file in the local running folder:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!File.Exists("file.txt"))
     {
         File.Create("file.txt");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `File.WriteAllText` Method  which creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     File.WriteAllText("file.txt","your text ");
}
```